# TypeError : Cannot read property 'role' of undefined after success rendering view Node.JS

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

i get a problem with my node.js application , it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined` which is after i put filter role in my hardcode , The code like this in my router

```
 var query1 = "SELECT payment_data .*, users.id as id_user , email , users.id_role as role FROM payment_data INNER JOIN users ON payment_data.username = users.username WHERE payment_data.username = '" + req.user.username + "' and transaction_code = " + connection.escape(req.params.tagihan) + "";
    connection.query(query1,function(err,rows){
        if (err){
            res.render('error',{
                responseCode : res.statusCode,
                error : 'Terjadi Kesalahan',
                message : err
            });
            res.end();
        }
        if (rows.length < 1){
            console.log(rows.length);
            res.render('error',{
                responseCode : res.statusCode,
                error : 'Terjadi kesalahan',
                message : err
            });
        }
        if (rows[0].role == "santri"){
            var querySantri = "SELECT * FROM data_santri WHERE id_user = " + rows[0].id_user + "";
            connection.query(querySantri,function(errDua,rowsDua){
                if (errDua){
                    res.render('error',{
                        responseCode : res.statusCode,
                        error : 'Terjadi Kesalahan',
                        message : errDua
                    }); 
                    res.end();
                }
                if (!rowsDua.length){
                    res.redirect('/beranda');
                    res.end();
                }
                var pdd = [];
                for(row in rows){
                    var pdd = rows[row];
                }
                var tghn = {
                    nama_lengkap : rowsDua[0].nama_lengkap,
                    email : rows[0].email,
                    alamat : rowsDua[0].alamat,
                    username : rows[0].username,
                    id_tagihan : rows[0].id,
                    nomor_tagihan : rows[0].transaction_code,
                    total_tagihan : rows[0].payment_total,
                    status_transaksi : rows[0].transaction_status,
                    tanggal_transaksi : rows[0].transaction_date,
                    channel_transaksi : rows[0].payment_channel,
                    data : pdd
                }
                // res.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
                // res.end();
                res.render('informasi/tagihan',{
                    auth: req.user,
                    tagihan : tghn,
                    moment : moment
                });
                res.end();
            });
        }else{
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
```

something strange in this debug is after the rendering view success , it shows normally , but in the end of the console return error so when i refresh my url again, my server goes down cause app crashed.

and another strange if the first time go to the url nothing happened, it means he accepted the rules of my filter 'role' so why it can rendered ?

and last thing if i put console log to returns a row, it returns 0 . why? actually there's row in that query.

Comment: Please learn Prepared Statements, this will have SQL Injection in no time.

Comment: thankyou , i use prepared statements by escaping values when i use insert statement or update statement.

Comment: You need to use it in `SELECT` statements too. I could easily put in `test'; DROP ALL DATABASES; --` as my username and wreck you server.

Comment: oh oke thankyou i'm going to use it again . i realize that after u suggest me. thankyou !

Comment: solved by following this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983520/express-js-routing-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent