# I am using A mongoose query for fetch result and send it in response

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my code:

```
    hArr = Array();
    hash.find({ hash_name: new RegExp('^' + req.body.hash + '$', "i") }, function(err, doc) {
        //Do your action here..
        if (err) {

            res.json({ response: 0, data: "fail", message: " Image Downloadding" });
        } else {
            for (var h = 0; h < doc.length; h++)
                hArr.push(doc[h].img_name);
            var unique = hArr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                return index == self.indexOf(elem);
            })

            Image.find().where('img').in(unique).exec(function(err, result) {
                res.json({ response: 1, data: result, message: "IMage List" });
            })
        }

    });
```

and  when  I run this code 
it show

```
Listening for request
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:359:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\learnNode\insta\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\learnNode\insta\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (E:\learnNode\insta\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:256:15)
    at E:\learnNode\insta\routes\api.js:830:25
    at E:\learnNode\insta\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2819:18
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

Comment: What's on file/line: E:\learnNode\insta\routes\api.js:830:25 ?

Comment: its     res.json({ response: 1, data: result, message: "IMage List" })

Answer (score 0):

Ok. According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983520/express-js-routing-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent), you may be sending more than one response.  Check your code. **unique** may have more than one element as you are using **arr.filter**. If so, **Image.find** may be called more than once sending more than one response in this route. You may check it putting some console.log's inside loops and callbacks to count.